# group xml file into datagrid

Tags: xml, wpf, datagrid

I want to group my xml binded datagrid...

This code I've got from the internet and worked ! 
But instead of binding DataContext to a list (addressList), I need to bind my XML file here...
How do I do that ?

```
        addressList = new ObservableCollection<Address>(){   <== this is an example ! But I've got a XML file ?! Howto ?
            new Address{ Country="Argentina", City="Buenos Aires", Street="Ldiary"},
            new Address{ Country="Argentina", City="Buenos Aires", Street="Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="Austria", City="Graz", Street="Ldiary Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="Austria", City="Salzburg", Street="Ldiary"},
            new Address{ Country="Belgium", City="Bruxelles", Street="Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="Belgium", City="Charleroi", Street="Ldiary Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="Brazil", City="Campinas", Street="Japanese"},
            new Address{ Country="Brazil", City="Resende", Street="English"},
            new Address{ Country="Brazil", City="Rio de Janeiro", Street="Ldiary Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="Canada", City="Montreal", Street="Ldiary Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="Canada", City="Montreal", Street="Ldiary Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="Denmark", City="Arhus", Street="English to Japanese"},
            new Address{ Country="Denmark", City="Kobenhavn", Street="Ldiary Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="Finland", City="Helsinki", Street="Ldiary Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="Finland", City="Oulu", Street="Ldiary Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="France", City="Lille", Street="Ldiary Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="France", City="Lyon", Street="Ldiary Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="France", City="Marseille", Street="Ldiary Translations"},
            new Address{ Country="France", City="Nantes", Street="English"},
            new Address{ Country="Germany", City="Aachen", Street="Japanese"},
            new Address{ Country="Germany", City="Berlin", Street="Ldiary Translations"}
        };

this.DataContext = addressList; <= Not 
CollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.DataContext) as  CollectionView;
        cv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Country"));
```

MY XAML:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="SmsData" XPath="/response"> => source added by code

    </XmlDataProvider>

    <local:RowColorConverter x:Key="RowColorConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SmsData}, XPath=conv/sms}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="-5,13,4,244" BorderThickness="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" IsEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged">

        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle AlternationCount="6" >
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="DataGridRow.Background" 
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GroupItem}, 
                    Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), Converter={StaticResource RowColorConverter}}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=msgid}" Width="100"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=imsgid}" Width="100"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=recipient}" Width="100"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=datetime}" Width="120" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=message}" Width="225" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

in cs (field msgid is element to group on):

```
XmlDataProvider dataProvider = this.FindResource("SmsData") as XmlDataProvider;
            dataProvider.Source = new Uri(someurl);

DataContext = this;
        CollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid1.DataContext) as CollectionView;
        cv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("msgid"));
```

my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<response>
    <conv>
        <sms><recipient>test</recipient><datetime/><message/></sms>
        <sms>
            <msgid>123456</msgid>
            <datetime>15-12-2012 21:36:55</datetime>
            <message>test</message>
        </sms>
    </conv>
</response>
```

Comment: Have tried parsing the XML file using XDocument or XmlDocument and then looping through the elements into the observable collection? You dont need bind the XML file, you need to bind the data from the XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind XML data directly in the Xaml.

Example:

Create an xml source from your file in your Window or Control resources

```
 <Window.Resources>
     <XmlDataProvider x:Key="AddressXML" XPath="/Address" Source="C:\AddressData.xml" />
 </Window.Resources>
```

Then you can bind to elements/Nodes in you document to your DataGrid or other controls.

```
  <Grid>
      <DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource AddressXML}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Address}" />
  </Grid>
```

If you post an example of your xml file I can give you a better explanation

CollectionViewSource in xaml

```
   xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
   xmlns:dat="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework"


<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="SmsData" XPath="/response" Source="C:\data.xml"/>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SmsView"  Source="{StaticResource SmsData}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="datetime" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="msgid" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource SmsView}"  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=conv/sms}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=msgid}" Width="100"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=imsgid}" Width="100"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=recipient}" Width="100"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=datetime}" Width="120" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=message}" Width="225" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: ohh.. so you want to bind your ObservableCollection to your DataGrid from code behind? or just group the data?

Comment: just group the data in my DataGrid based on xml-binded file... but only way I found to do it, is with ObservableCollection (like first code at my beginpost)

Comment: and you want to do this all in xaml? and does address = smsdata?

Comment: yes like first code in my post (also with xaml). address = smsdata? No has nothing to do with eachother.

Comment: ok, if I undersand correctly, you just want collectionviewsource in xaml and that "Address"data is not used anywhere?

Comment: Forget about Address :p is sample code to integrate in my code. Simply said: I just want to group on "msgid" in my datagrid with my xml-binded source

Comment: Thanks for that ! It worked perfect !! But now when I see the result, I don't want to group on msgid anymore... but grouping on "conv" (as you can see in my xml). How do I do that ? Can't get that working

Comment: I tried to change <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="msgid" /> to <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="conv" /> but does not word